# Spark SQL does not work with Hive View when Hive Regex Column support is enabled

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Our team has a bunch of Hive QL, so when migrating to spark, we want to reuse the existng HQL which uses Hive [Regex Column Specification](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-REGEXColumnSpecification) like `` SELECT `(ds)?+.+` FROM ``.

This could be done simply be simply enable the following configuration:

```
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.parser.quotedRegexColumnNames', 'true')
```

However, with the above configuration enabled, querying any Hive view using Spark SQL failed and Spark SQL Analyzer will complain

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Invalid usage of '*' in expression 'unresolvedextractvalue';"
```

A simple pyspark script to reproduce the issue is like the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def main():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test_spark').enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    spark.conf.set('hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode', 'nonstrict')
    spark.conf.set('spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode','dynamic')
    spark.conf.set('spark.sql.parser.quotedRegexColumnNames', 'true')

    spark_sql = r'''
    SELECT
        id_listing
    FROM
        <A Hive View>
    WHERE
        ds = '2019-03-09'
'''
    result = spark.sql(spark_sql)
    print(result.count())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I was wondering if there is a way to make Regex Column specification and Hive View coexist in Spark.

I observed this behavior in both Spark 2.3.0 and 2.4.0

Comment: Did you try with a simple query and see that it worked here? only regex doesnt work?

Comment: @JimTodd Even simple query against a Hive view like `SELECT id_listing FROM
<A Hive View>` does not work, you can see in the SQL I didn't use the regex column specification in the select clause.

Comment: @leon Did you find solution to this?
I am facing same issue
Can you please provide me how did you resolved it?